# Accessing different model attributes based on conditional

Tags: ruby, oop, ruby-on-rails-5

I am curious if there is a nice way to access a model's attribute as a variable.

```
    if I18n.locale == :ja
      pref = Prefecture.all.find { |pr| pr.name == province }
    else
      pref = Prefecture.all.find { |pr| pr.name_e == province }
    end
```

Something like this pseudocode:

```
    ...find { |pr| pr.(I18n.locale == :ja ? name : name_e) == province }
```

I have tried storing the block in a proc, but I don' have much experience using procs (if that approach will work here). Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Is this an ActiveRecord model you are accessing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
attr =
case I18n.locale
when :ja then :name
else :name_e

pref = Prefecture.find {|pr| pr.send(attr) == province}
```

Comment: Ah, I forgot about #send! Thanks for the suggestion, I think that's essentially what I was looking for.